# How to connect Django project with MS SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, django, python-3.x, server

I am beginner in Django framework and trying to connect Django project with MS sQL server on my localhost. I have tried a few of libs like pyodbc-azure but it is not working in my case and I am getting the errors.

> "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.5\bin\runnerw.exe"
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe"
>   C:/Users/hyaqub/PycharmProjects/SpotDash/manage.py runserver 8000
>   Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x04A1BD68> Traceback (most recent
>   call last): File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc\base.py", line 55,
>   in  import pyodbc as Database ImportError: DLL load failed:
>   The specified module could not be found.
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line
>   225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 109, in inner_run autoreload.raise_last_exception() File
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line
>   248, in raise_last_exception raise _exception[1] File "C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 337, in execute autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)() File
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line
>   225, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs) File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 24, in
>   setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS) File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line
>   112, in populate app_config.import_models() File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198,
>   in import_models self.models_module =
>   import_module(models_module_name) File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 127, in
>   import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load File
>   "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked File
>   "", line 728, in exec_module
>   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py",
>   line 2, in  from django.contrib.auth.base_user import
>   AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py",
>   line 47, in  class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model): File
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line
>   101, in *new* new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta,
>   app_label)) File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line
>   305, in add_to_class value.contribute_to_class(cls, name) File
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line
>   203, in contribute_to_class self.db_table =
>   truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()) File
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 33,
>   in *getattr* return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item) File
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in
>   *getitem* backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE']) File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in
>   load_backend return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name) File
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\importlib__init__.py", line
>   127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:],
>   package, level) File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django_pyodbc\base.py", line 58,
>   in  raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading pyodbc module:
>   %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading
>   pyodbc module: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
>   found.

**Please guide me how can I achieve this. It would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states that you are missing a DLL/module. I am not sure what process you went to install, but [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-pyodbc-python-development?view=sql-server-2017) state that you need [Install the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files?view=sql-server-2017#installing-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server), which should include all of the necessary DLL's